# What is making my page content load and suddenly disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I'm adjusting a form in a website that has several parts. The goal is when we load the page, the initial input appears and the other inputs just appear after the one before has an adequate value.
On the first page everything seems ok (I added a few more inputs to the original), when I pass on to the second page the first input seems to appear and suddenly disappear, not allowing the user to fill out the value and thus leaving the page blank.
I can't understand what's making the loading problem. Below is the code.

passo3.ejs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">    
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <!-- <h1><%= __('calculadora.title') %></h1> -->
            <h2><%= __('calculadora.subtitle_3_revestimentos') %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-dark" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-info" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;"></div>

    <div class="progress">    
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-dark" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="4" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= progressBar %>%"></div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 form-inline"></div> 

        <div class="form-group col-sm-1 form-inline col-margin"></div> 
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 form-inline form-option-div">           
            <!-- image depends on option in step 1-->
            <div class="btn-image-div-absolute d-flex align-items-end">
                <img src="/img/calculadora_p3/fachada_<%= lang %>.png" class="btn-image-absolute rounded mx-auto image_overlay image_base">
                <img src="/img/calculadora_p3/fachada_ac.png" class="btn-image-absolute rounded mx-auto image_overlay ac" style="display:none;">
                <img src="/img/calculadora_p3/fachada_af.png" class="btn-image-absolute rounded mx-auto image_overlay af" style="display:none;">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 form-option-div">           
            <h3 class="form-subtitle"><%= __('calculadora.cobertura') %></h3>
            <!-- 10 --> 
            <% var _Q = {
                tabindex: 1,
                number: "10",
                name: "rev_tipo",
                hiddenOnStart: false,
                errorInput: false,
                additionalClasses: "form-control",
                units: ""
            }; %>
            <% include ./_question_typeB.ejs %>

            <!-- 10A --> 
            <% _Q = {
                tabindex: 2,
                number: "10A",
                name: "rev_outro",
                hiddenOnStart: true,
                errorInput: true,
                additionalClasses: "valid_number",
                units: "[kg/m<sup>2</sup>]"
            }; %>
            <% include ./_question_typeA.ejs %>
        

            <!-- 11 --> 
            <% _Q = {
                tabindex: 3,
                number: "11",
                name: "afmc",
                hiddenOnStart: true,
                errorInput: true,
                additionalClasses: "valid_selectize_number",
                units: "a<sub>c</sub>&nbsp;[m]"
            }; %>
            <% include ./_question_typeB.ejs %>

            

            <div class="part2" style="display:none;">
                <h3 class="form-subtitle"><%= __('calculadora.fachada') %></h3>
            
                <!-- [9] 12 (20) --> 
                <% _Q = {
                    tabindex: 4,
                    number: "12",
                    name: "ori_rev_fachada",
                    hiddenOnStart: false,
                    errorInput: false,
                    additionalClasses: "form-control",
                    units: ""
                }; %>
                <% include ./_question_typeB.ejs %>


                <!-- [10] 9 (31) --> 
                <% _Q = {
                    tabindex: 5,
                    number: "13",
                    name: "n_fachadas_abertas",
                    hiddenOnStart: true,
                    errorInput: false,
                    additionalClasses: "form-control",
                    units: ""
                }; %>
                <% include ./_question_typeB.ejs %>


                <!-- [11] 10 (32) --> 
                <% _Q = {
                    tabindex: 6,
                    number: "14",
                    name: "n_empenas_abertas",
                    hiddenOnStart: true,
                    errorInput: false,
                    additionalClasses: "form-control",
                    units: ""
                }; %>
                <% include ./_question_typeB.ejs %>


                <!-- [12] 11 (9) --> 
                <% _Q = {
                    tabindex: 7,
                    number: "15",
                    name: "rev_fachada",
                    hiddenOnStart: true,
                    errorInput: false,
                    additionalClasses: "form-control",
                    units: ""
                }; %>
                <% include ./_question_typeB.ejs %>
                

                <!-- 13 (10) --> 
                <% _Q = {
                    tabindex: 8,
                    number: "16",
                    name: "afmf",
                    hiddenOnStart: true,
                    errorInput: true,
                    additionalClasses: "valid_selectize_number",
                    units: "a<sub>f</sub>&nbsp;[m]"
                }; %>
                <% include ./_question_typeB.ejs %>

            
            </div> <!-- part 2 -->

            <div class="btn_submit_div" style="display:none;">
                <button tabindex="10" type="button" class="btn_submit btn btn-dark btn-md"><%= __('calculadora.seguinte') %></button>
            </div>

        </div><!-- form group -->
       

        



    </div><!-- row -->






    <div style="height: 70px; width:100%">
    </div>


    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="<%= step %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="arq" value="<%= calcData.arq %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="vao" value="<%= calcData.vao %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="h1" value="<%= calcData.h1 %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="hc" value="<%= calcData.hc %>">


    <div class="calculadora_inputs">

        <% if( typeof report != "undefined" ){ %>
            <form id="form_calculadora" name="form_calculadora" action="/calculadora" method="GET">
                <input id="reportId" type="hidden" class="" name="reportId" value="<%= report._id %>">
                <input id="nextStep" type="hidden" class="" name="nextStep" value="<%= +report.step +1 %>">
        <% } %>
                
        <input type="hidden" name="v" value="<%= calcData.v %>"><!-- calculated on server with step 2 inputs, needs to be here to be included in query string inputs -->
        <input type="hidden" class="sync_rev_tipo required" name="rev_tipo">
        <input type="hidden" class="sync_rev_outro required" name="rev_outro">
        <input type="hidden" class="sync_afmc required" name="afmc">
        <input type="hidden" class="sync_n_fachadas_abertas required" name="n_fachadas_abertas">
        <input type="hidden" class="sync_n_empenas_abertas required" name="n_empenas_abertas">
        <input type="hidden" class="sync_rev_fachada required" name="rev_fachada">
        <input type="hidden" class="sync_ori_rev_fachada required" name="ori_rev_fachada">
        <input type="hidden" class="sync_afmf required" name="afmf">
        
        <% if( typeof report != "undefined" ){ %>
            </form>
        <% } %>

    </div>
</div>

<script>resetCalculatorText = "<%=  __('resetCalculatorText') %>";</script>
<script src="/js/calculadora_passo<%= step %>.js"></script>
```

_question_typeB.ejs

```
<% 
var _visible = '', _errorPop = '', _errorPopClass='', _additionalClasses='', _selectOptions=[];
if( _Q.hiddenOnStart ) {
    _visible=`style="display:none"`;
}
    
if( _Q.errorInput ){
    let _content = __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.errorText`);
    
    _errorPop=`data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="left" data-content="${_content}" data-html="true" data-container=".calculator-input-group.step${_Q.number}"`;
   
    _errorPopClass = 'error-popover';
}

if( _Q.additionalClasses ){
    _additionalClasses = _Q.additionalClasses;
}

if(  __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.selectOptions`) ){
    _selectOptions = __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.selectOptions`);
}
%>

<h4 class="input_label step<%= _Q.number %>" <%- _visible %>><%= __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.inputLabel`) %></h4>
<div class="input-group calculator-input-group step<%= _Q.number %>" <%- _visible %>>
    
    <% console.log(_Q.units) %>
    <% if( _Q.units ){ %>
        <a class="<%= _errorPopClass %>"" <%- _errorPop %> > 
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text calculator-input-prepend"><%- _Q.units %></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    <% } %> 
    
    
    <select data-tab="<%= _Q.tabindex %>" class="sync_<%= _Q.name %> middle calculator-input <%= _errorPopClass %> <%- _additionalClasses %>" placeholder="<%= __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.inputPlaceholder`) %>" title="<%= __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.inputTitle`) %>" aria-label="<%= __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.inputTitle`) %>">
        <% console.log(_selectOptions.length) %>
        <% if( _selectOptions.length ){ %>
            <option selected disabled><%- __(`calculadora.escolhaUmaOpcao`) %></option>

        
            <% _selectOptions.forEach(function( eachOption){ %>
                <option value="<%= eachOption.val %>"><%- eachOption.title %></option>
            <% }) %>
        <% } %>    
    </select>
    
    
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text calculator-input-append">
        <a tabindex="99" class="btn btn-sm btn-link btn-block" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="left" title="<%= __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.helperTitle`) %>" data-content="<%= __(`calculadora.q${_Q.number}.helperContent`) %>"><i class="far fa-question-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

calculadora_passo3.js

```
 //store the instance of the selectize components
    var $selectize_8;
    var selectizeControl_8;

    var $selectize_13;
    var selectizeControl_13;


    $(document).ready(function() {

        
        
    
        //initialization
        function _init(){
            
            //add a property to help icon on Afmc so it can be added dynamicaly to help popover when clicked
            //after this add the event to the help button to get the aria-described with the id of the popover and manipulate the content
            //replacing ${1} by data-par1 value. Because this can be used anywhere i'm adding this event to main calculadoraFrontEnd.js file
            let afmc = (+$('[name="v"]').val() ).toFixed(2);
            let afmf = +$('[name="h1"]').val()-0.5;

            console.log(afmc);
            console.log(afmf);

            $('.step11 .input-group-append .btn-link').attr('data-par1', afmc );
            //same for afmf on step 16
            $('.step16 .input-group-append .btn-link').attr('data-par1', afmf );

            scrollTo($('header'));
        }


        








       //populate select box
        function populateSelect_8(){
          
             //destroy select if already exists
            if( selectizeControl_8){
                selectizeControl_8.destroy();
            }

            //initiate the selectize component and store it's instance
            $selectize_8 = $('select.sync_afmc').selectize( {
                options: calcularAfastamentoMadreCobertura(),
                valueField: 'val',
                labelField: 'title',
                searchField: 'title',
                sortField: function(item1, item2) {
                    return item1.value - item2.value;
                },
                createOnBlur: true,
                create: true,
                openOnFocus: true,
                onChange: function(input){
                    //prevent clear method (input becomes null) to trigger "not a number" again
                    if(!input) return;
                    
                    let length_v = $('[name="v"]').val();//calcularComprimentoViga();
                    //ignore +2 place decimals
                    let ratio = Math.round((length_v / input)*100)/100;

                   //check if the input exists in the original options calculation function
                   let originalOptions = calcularAfastamentoMadreCobertura();
                   let originalOption = false;
                   
                   if (originalOptions.filter(function(option) { return option.val === input; }).length > 0) {
                        originalOption= true;
                   }

                   if( !$.isNumeric(input)  ||  (Math.floor(ratio) != ratio && !originalOption ) ) { 
                        //showMessage("Error - Not valid number", "alert-danger");
                        showMessage( $(this.$wrapper[0]) );
                        //clear last added value
                        selectizeControl_8.clear();
                        //remove last added value from list
                        selectizeControl_8.removeOption(input);
                        //reopen dropdown
                        selectizeControl_8.open();
                    }else{
                        //clear error message
                            clearMessage( $(this.$wrapper[0]) );
                    }
                },
                onInitialize: function(){
                    $(this.$wrapper[0]).find(":input").attr('tabindex', $(this.$wrapper[0]).parent().find('.selectized').data('tab') ) ;    
                },
                onFocus: function(){
                    showOnlyTheRightImage("ac");
                },
                render: {
                        item: function(item, escape) {
                            return '<div>' +
                                (item.title ? '<span class="selectize_title">' + escape(item.title) + '</span>' : '') +
                            '</div>';
                        },
                        option: function(item, escape) {
                            return '<div>' +
                                '<span class="selectize_title"><strong>' + (item.title ? escape(item.title) : escape(item.val)) + '</strong>' +
                                (item.subtitle ? '<span class="selectize_subtitle">&emsp;' + escape(item.subtitle) +  '</span>' : '') +  '</span>'
                            '</div>';
                        },
                }
         });//options

            //store object instnace so we can handle events
            selectizeControl_8 = $selectize_8[0].selectize;
          
        }//function

        









        //populate select box
        function populateSelect_13(){
            
            let af_array = [];
            

             //destroy select if already exists
            if( selectizeControl_13){
                selectizeControl_13.destroy();
            }

            //initiate the selectize component and store it's instance
            $selectize_13 = $('select.sync_afmf').selectize( {
                options: calcularAfastamentoMadresFachada(),
                valueField: 'val',
                labelField: 'title',
                searchField: 'title',
                sortField: function(item1, item2) {
                    return item1.value - item2.value;
                },
                createOnBlur: true,
                create: true,
                openOnFocus: true,
                onChange: function(input){
                   //prevent clear method (input becomes null) to trigger "not a number" again
                   if(!input) return
                    
                   //h from form inputs
                   let length_h = parseFloat( $('[name="h1"]').val() );
                   //ignore +2 place decimals
                   let ratio = Math.round((length_h / input)*100)/100;
                   
                   //check if the input exists in the original options calculation function
                   let originalOptions = calcularAfastamentoMadresFachada();
                   let originalOption = false;
                   
                   if (originalOptions.filter(function(option) { return option.val === input; }).length > 0) {
                        originalOption= true;
                   }

                   if( !$.isNumeric(input)  ||  (Math.floor(ratio) != ratio && !originalOption ) ) { 
                        
                        showMessage( $(this.$wrapper[0]) );
                        //clear last added value
                        selectizeControl_13.clear();
                        //remove last added value from list
                        selectizeControl_13.removeOption(input);
                        //reopen dropdown
                        selectizeControl_13.open();
                    }else{
                        //clear error message
                        clearMessage( $(this.$wrapper[0]) );
                    }
                },
                onInitialize: function(){
                    $(this.$wrapper[0]).find(":input").attr('tabindex', $(this.$wrapper[0]).parent().find('.selectized').data('tab') ) ;  
                },
                onFocus: function(){
                    showOnlyTheRightImage("af");
                },
                render: {
                        item: function(item, escape) {
                            return '<div>' +
                                (item.title ? '<span class="selectize_title">' + escape(item.title) + '</span>' : '') +
                            '</div>';
                        },
                        option: function(item, escape) {
                            return '<div>' +
                                '<span class="selectize_title"><strong>' + (item.title ? escape(item.title) : escape(item.val)) + '</strong>' +
                                (item.subtitle ? '<span class="selectize_subtitle">&emsp;' + escape(item.subtitle) +  '</span>' : '') +  '</span>'
                            '</div>';
                        },
                }
         });//options

            //store object instnace so we can handle events
            selectizeControl_13 = $selectize_13[0].selectize;
          
        }//function









        //allow only numbers and decimal point
        $('.group_option_inputs_div').keypress('div.valid_selectize_number', function(e) {
        
            //only allow number and dot characters
            if ( (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which !== 46) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            //dont allow paste
        }).on('paste', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });




        $('.calculator-input').on('focus', function(){
            //hide all except base image
            $('.image_overlay').not('.image_base').hide();
        });





        //FLOW -------------------------------------------------------
        // Step 10 only to show 10A
        $('[name="rev_tipo"]').on('input', function(){
            //if valid activate next input
            if( $(this).val() == '6' ){
                $('.step10A').show();
            }else{
                $('.step10A').hide();
                //also clear rev_outro input (only for option 6 - outro)
                $('.sync_rev_outro').val('').trigger("change");
            }
        });


        // Step 10, 10A
        $('[name="rev_tipo"], [name="rev_outro"]').on('input', function(){
            
            let tipo = $('[name="rev_tipo"]').val();
            let outro = $('[name="rev_outro"]').val();

            let valid = true;
            
            //nothing selected or "other" without specifing what "other" is
            if( tipo == '' || (tipo == '6' && outro == '') ){
                valid = false;
            }

            //if valid activate next input
            if( !valid ){
                $('.step10, .step11, .step12, .step13, .step14, .step15, .step16').hide();
                $('.btn_submit_div').hide();
            }else{
                $('.step10').show().trigger("input");
                populateSelect_8();
                //scrollTo( $('.step8') );
            }
        });








        // step 8
        $('[name="afmc"]').on('input', function(){
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $('.step11, .step12, .step13, .step14, .step15, .step16').hide();
                $('.btn_submit_div').hide();
            }else{
                //show parte 2 of form
                $('.part2').show();
                $('.step11').show().trigger("input");
                //scrollTo( $('.step9') );
            }
        });






         // step [9] 12 (10)
         $('[name="ori_rev_fachada"]').on('input', function(){
            $('.step12, .step13, .step14, .step15, .step16').hide();
            $('.btn_submit_div').hide();

            if( $(this).val() != ''){
             
                if( $(this).val() == '0' ||  $(this).val() == '1' ){ 
                    $('.step12').show().trigger("input");
                    
                }else{
                    $('.sync_rev_fachada').val('');
                    $('.sync_n_empenas_abertas').val('');
                    $('.sync_n_fachadas_abertas').val('');
                    //also clear afmf input (only for option 0 - vertical)
                    $('.sync_afmf').val('');

                    $('.btn_submit_div').show();
                    //scrollTo( $('.btn_submit_div') );
                   
                 }  
            }
        });





        // step [10] 9 (31)
        $('[name="n_fachadas_abertas"]').on('input', function(){
            
            $('.step13, .step14, .step15, .step16').hide();
            $('.btn_submit_div').hide();
            
            if($(this).val() != ''){
                $('.step13').show().trigger("input");
                //scrollTo( $('.step10') );
            }
        });








        // step [11] 10 (32)
        $('[name="n_empenas_abertas"]').on('input', function(){
            
            $('.step14, .step15, .step16').hide();
            $('.btn_submit_div').hide();
            
            if( $(this).val() != ''){
                $('.step14').show().trigger("input");
            }
        });







        // step [12] 11 (9)
        $('[name="rev_fachada"]').on('input', function(){
            if( $(this).val() == ''){
                $('.step15, .step16').hide();
                $('.btn_submit_div').hide();
            }else{
                //if orientação do revestimento = horizontal, afmf will not be required
                if( $('.sync_ori_rev_fachada').val() == '1' ){
                    $('.sync_afmf').val('');
                    $('.step15').hide();
                    $('.btn_submit_div').show();
                    //scrollTo( $('.btn_submit_div') );
                }else{
                    populateSelect_13(); 
                    $('.step15').show().trigger("input"); 
                    $('.btn_submit_div').hide(); 
                }

                
                //scrollTo( $('.step12') );
            }
        });
        





       



        // step 13 (10)
        $('[name="afmf"]').on('input', function(){
            if( $(this).val() == ''){
                $('.btn_submit_div').hide();
            }else{
                $('.btn_submit_div').show();
                //scrollTo( $('.btn_submit_div') );
            }
        });
        //------------------------------------------------------------




        

        function calcularAfastamentoMadreCobertura(){

            let rev = $('[name="rev_tipo"]').val(); //defined in this form
            let arq = $('[name="arq"]').val();
            let vao = $('[name="vao"]').val();
            let h = $('[name="h"]').val();
            let hc = $('[name="hc"]').val();
            let ret = [];
            
            let A = 1.0; //caso para arq = 2 e 3
            let B = 3.0; //caso o revestimento da cobertura seja qq tipo de sandwich
            
            if(arq == "1"){
                A = 0.5;
            }else if(arq == "4"){
                A = 2.0;
            }

            if(rev == "0"){//Chapa Simples - Bac Acier
                B = 2.0;  
            }else if(rev == "1" || rev == "6" ){//fotovoltaico e outro
                B = 1.6;
            }

            //suggest more values
            let variation = [0, 1, 2];
            //this will be the suggested options available to the user in the select box
            let suggested = [];

            //calculate options and add them to suggested array
            for(let i=0; i<variation.length; i++){
                
                let distanciaViga = Math.sqrt( (vao * A)**2 + (hc - h)**2 ) - 0.5;
                let afmc = distanciaViga / ( Math.ceil( (distanciaViga / B) + variation[i] ) );
    
                let result = parseFloat( afmc ).toFixed(2);
    
                suggested.push({val:result, title:result });
            }

            return suggested;
        }







        function calcularAfastamentoMadresFachada(){
            //tipo de revestimento da fachada ( 0=chapa simples, 1=painael sandwich, 2=outro)
            let rev_fachada = $('[name="rev_fachada"]').val();
            //altura dos pilares
            let h = $('[name="h"]').val();
            //look for values close to this (don't know why this specifically)
            
            let ret = [];
            let constant = 3; //other cases then "chapa simples"
            
            if( rev_fachada === '0') constant = 2;

            let calc = parseFloat( (h - 0.5) / Math.ceil( (h - 0.5)/constant ) ).toFixed(2);
        
            ret.push({val:calc , title:calc})
            
            return ret;
        }







        //hide all overlay images except the one with the specific class to the question on focus
        function showOnlyTheRightImage(specificClass){
            $('.image_overlay').not('.image_base').hide();
            $('.image_overlay.'+specificClass).show();
        }




       
        //initialize stuff
        setTimeout(function() { 
            _init();
        }, 10);//only enough for this to be last

    });//document ready
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Emphasis on the *minimal*.

Comment: Does it still do it if you remove the call to `_init()`?   Yes, then `_init()` isn't your problem and you can temporarily remove that code.   No (it now works) then `_init()` is the problem and start stepping through.  Repeat for each feature.